# Selecting code chunk in Rmarkdown

Tags: visual-block, custom-text-object

I am writing an RMarkdown file, which is a document that is a hybrid of text and R code. Here is an example of what that document could look like:

````
Here is an example of text within my Rmarkdown file. 
This is used to describe the code block below:

```{r}
dataframe <- outcome.df %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(Hospital, State) %>%
  arrange(desc(HeartAttackDeath)) %>%
```

Here is an example of another text block
And the following is an example of another code chunk:

```{r}
result <- lapply(names(dataframe), complete.cases)
```
````

I would like to move all of the code to another document. How would I go about selecting just the code, using vim? i.e. everything between ```` ```{r} ```` and ```` ``` ````

Comment: Is this question [on topic](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's not about Vi or Vim, but rather another editor, RStudio.

Comment: Anyway, we could try to help him how to do that on Vim...

Comment: I read the "on topic" page, and found this:" It need not be a stand-alone program; a plugin for Visual Studio that gives vi-like behavior is on-topic, but only the vi-like behavior is." I'll clarify that I would like to accomplish this through the vim bindings on RStudio. If mods still think this is off topic, feel free to close it.

Comment: Like @JoãoA.Toledo said, I would still prefer to solve this in a vim way. If anyone could help me accomplish this in vim, that would be great as well!

Comment: Edited question to be on topic. I go back and fourth between RStudio and vim, so solving this in vim would be equally beneficial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a prime case for a [text object](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#text-objects), but unfortunately, Vim doesn't recognize ```` ```{R} ```` or ```` ``` ```` as text object delimiters.

There's at least three options that do work:

**1.** Click and drag with the mouse. A bit blasphemous, perhaps, but it can get the job done if there's not too much needing to be selected and your Vim or equivalent was built with mouse support.

---

**2.** Position your cursor on the first line of what you want selected, press <kbd>Shift + v</kbd>, then use <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> or <kbd>j</kbd> to jump down to the last line you want selected. Having visible line numbers can be helpful here. Absolute line numbers for the count for <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>, relative line numbers for the count for <kbd>j</kbd>.

---

**3.** This requires a little set up, but doesn't require you to think about how many lines you're selecting, and makes repeated use almost trivial.

````
:let @/ = "```"
:let @a = gnVnkoj
````

This can then be used by positioning the cursor above the section you want to select (even above the delimiter, but after any preceding sections' delimiters), then just running <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>.

Explanation:

The first line, simply sets the "last used" search pattern without actually jumping to it by directly setting the search register. The second line sets up a macro in the `a` register. <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> jumps to the next item of the last used search pattern (should the the opening delimiter) and enters visual mode, selecting it. <kbd>Shift+v</kbd> switches to line-wise visual mode. <kbd>n</kbd> jumps to the next found instance of the search pattern (should be the closing delimiter). <kbd>k</kbd> moves up a line to deselect the delimiter. <kbd>o</kbd> moves the cursor to the other end of the selection and "reverses" the selection, so it starts at the bottom and ends at the top, where the cursor now is.  <kbd>j</kbd> moves down a line to deselect the opening delimiter.

Comment: #3 seems to be the best solution for me. It makes the most sense to me, and is something I can do without spending too much time on setting up commands. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
ggqrq
```

and then

````
:execute '/\%>' . line('.') . 'l^```{r}' | +1,/^```$/-1y R | normal @:
````

What it does:

`gg`  goes to first position in the buffer;

`qrq` starts to record a macro on register `r` and ends it immediately; it simply clears the register `r`;

```` :execute '/\%>' . line('.') . 'l^```{r}' ```` searches for a line after current one (see `:help /\%>l`) with the pattern ```` ^```{r} ````;

`|` separates this command from the next;

```` +1,/^```$/-1y R ```` yanks to register `R` from the next line till the next one that starts with ```` ^```$ ```` less one; as we used capital `R`, the new content is appended to what was already there;

`|` separates this command from the next;

`normal @:` re-executes last `:` command (this whole line).

At the end you will have all the content you want in the `r` register.

Comment: Thanks! This seemed to work in vim (not in RStudio)

Answer (score 1):

#### `if` of vim-textobj-markdown

When you use vim and do not mind to use a plugin, you can always check

https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user/wiki

In your case you will find the plugin https://github.com/coachshea/vim-textobj-markdown

This plugin maps by default `if` to address the inner of a code block.

There are more plugins which you could consider, e.g.

- [vim-sandwich](https://github.com/machakann/vim-sandwich) provides interactive text objects by querying the beginning and end specifier:
  [`is <Plug>(textobj-sandwich-query-i)`](https://github.com/machakann/vim-sandwich/blob/master/doc/textobj-sandwich.txt#L148-L149).

Also creating your own textobject would be an option:

- https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Creating_new_text_objects

If you get fancy, you could write a plugin based on [targets.vim](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim) similar to [line-targets.vim](https://github.com/wellle/line-targets.vim) to get a very comprehensive experience of textobjects, something like

```
 if  af  If  Af
inf anf Inf Anf
ilf alf Ilf Alf
```

There is a pending [PR](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/pull/1384) for [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) (a LaTeX plugin) to define textobjects for LaTeX commands and environments based on targets.vim: see the [cheatsheet for a quick look](https://github.com/kiryph/vimtex/blob/text_obj_targets/cheatsheet.md#environments).

However, I doubt that any of this will help you in RStudio.

Comment: While this could be really useful in my own setup, I don't have the necessary permissions to install vim plugins in my current work environment. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am just curious: Are you sure you do not have write permissions in your home directory? If you can have a vimrc, then you can have also your own plugins. Plugins are so to speak vimrc files under `$HOME/.vim/pack/...`.

Comment: Looks like I do actually have write permissions! That just opened up a whole array of options for me. Thanks!